# Wrapping a link around an image destroys flexbox layout and causes browser rendering quirks

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

*Struggling to find the right title that isn't just a mixture of "help" and "what, CSS, why?!" so hopefully a couple of you geniuses will find this...!*

I have two columns. Each of them has a full-width div inside it which contains a logo. The images are quite different shapes, one being a square and one being a more panoramic aspect ratio. To achieve a balanced look, the images are set to a max-width of 50% and a max-height of 100%. Flexbox is used to center the images both horizontally and vertically.

They look perfectly fine.

```
// working before wrapping images with links
section.working {
  div.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    img {
      max-width: 50%;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

**And then I needed to add links.**

https://codepen.io/lenoz/pen/VwZyeOG

This is the problem reduced to its most simple, in that the bottom row was the original code I was using to get the perfect layout, and the top row shows what happens when the images were wrapped in  tags to make them links. Some points of note:

- colours added just to help distinguish boundaries a little - useful for detecting when the link (red background) is no longer constricted to the size of the image inside it (as it ideally should be)
- the two columns are separate in the code and not part of a shared container - i.e. one cannot inform the height of the other (want to fix this with CSS not JS)

I should mention that of course there was no way adding links would *just work* - the `<a>` tags come in between the flex container and the flex item, so obviously they will mess with the layout.

**Much appreciated if you can help me find a CSS solution.**

---

*Still here? Read on if you want some more info on my attempts to fix, with a side portion of Chrome weirdness.*

It should also go without saying I've spent ages fiddling with this, so here's another link showing some of my efforts that have gotten close: https://codepen.io/lenoz/pen/pozpjVq

The top row (`section.help`) is my latest attempt, but is a bit of a mess simply because I stopped half way, having suffered frustration sufficient to lead to me making this post.

The middle row, which I'm calling `section.weirdness`, actually seemed to be a solution for a hot minute. If you're using Chrome, like I am, when you look at the Codepen link you *may* see nothing on these blue blocks?
[image: blue blocks with nothing on them]

But try removing the `display: flex` attribute from `div.flex` and, if your Chrome is like my Chrome, you'll see this:
[image: chrome is being weird]

Now, add that **same** `display: flex` attribute back on the **same** `div.flex` selector and you'll see that suddenly the blue blocks are not blank:
[image: back again!]

How strange is that? Browser rendering bug or what?

Now find the `max-width` or `max-height` attributes on `div.image`, toggle one of those off and then on again and you'll see that everything suddenly looks right again:
[image: back to perfection]

Somehow, without changing any CSS other than toggling it, we've gone from no links showing up at all, to them showing up and looking perfect. You can see how I'd managed to confuse myself into thinking I had got it working!

Answer (score 5):

Just add style="display: contents" to your anchors

- "display: contents" causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself

```
 <div>
      <a style="display: contents" href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your Codepen example:

```
.flex > a {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

div.flex a > img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Any immediate child of a container with `display: flex` is flex item. To prevent that item from growing or shrinking we must set `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties to 0. In my case I used `flex: 0 0 50%` shorthand for that. That last value of 50% is from your initial image `max-width` property. That + `height:100%` will make sure that `<a>` behaves like images in your original example. 
Now the fun part: use `display: flex` again on `<a>` to make the *image* flex item again. Since `<a>` is already properly sized we can set `max-width` and `max-height` to `00% to fill available space.

Using `margin: auto` is a neat trick to center both horizontally and vertically flex child inside of flex container (works only when there is one child).

sidenote: I used `important` to override specificity without changing markup but I would advise against it and put new CSS class on both `a` and `img`.

---

**UPDATE**

working fork (Chrome only): https://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/wvwpWbx?editors=1100

```
section.broken {
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  a {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Teo! In your fork you can see that the link is no longer constricted to the size of the child image as it should be (all that red background). I _may_ have forgotten to mention this as a requirement in my post - sorry - but I would consider it to be much more user-friendly to find a solution where there is no visible red background.

Comment: @MattMorrison I updated my fork, no red background :)

Comment: Checked your new link - there's no overhanging link (red) on the 1000x300 image, but the 500x500 has overhanging link and is no longer even centered. Sorry! https://i.imgur.com/aM4ryAv.png

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

I've changed the columns to be flex contexts but retained an inner div to serve as the 50% width constraint. When the `img`s are allowed to set their own height explicitly all the other constraints around them flow into place without much fuss, and because the anchors don't have any layout rules, they manage to avoid having any clickable areas outside their image.

With the same max-height on the images, they'll match in the same way as your `.working` class as long as their containers are the same width.

```css
section {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column > div {
  max-width: 50%;
}

img {
  display: block; /* get rid of bottom gap */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column">
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.png" />
      </a>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's decent Neptunus, thanks. I'd **love** to be able to fix it without specifying the same max-height on the images as the height of the main container, but certainly it's a good fix. The issue is definitely all about passing down height and max-height understandings through the levels, and even if your solution doesn't fix _that_, it still fixes my main problem. Maybe I shouldn't be aiming to fix the bigger issue! Thanks again, will mark yours as solution unless anything comes along without needing to specify image height!

Comment: Well, in fact you don't need to set a height on the main container at all with this approach. The containers are strictly concerned about width, and the image will use up all the width that it can until it reaches its maximum height. The container will expand vertically to contain any height you choose to give your images :)

Comment: Ah, but in order to take off the max-height from the container div (.column) you added `display: flex` to the section. The real page is a lot more complex than my reduced example, and I can't mess with the section styles, that's why one of my specifications in the original post was pointing out that they aren't (on the real page) part of a shared container - the `section` element as per the examples in use here doesn't really exist. Anyway, thanks again for your original version - am using it now, and having to specify max-height in two places is not the end of the world.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help. If it's the same max-height in two places, that might be a good place for a CSS variable.